# how to generically import a gltf model in threejs?

Tags: javascript, import, three.js, model, gltf

I need to create a generic advanced viewer in three js which could generate Gltf files. How could I get every information about each component of the model?

I try to search into the loader class with loader.load()  of THREE.GLTFLOADER, I found the information ( in scene.children which are the models' components) but I can't make it generic.

Is there any libraries or function that give you each component? 
like the function .getElementById, something like .GetAllComponents or .GetMaterialsTextures (like i need to get every path for texture and model'components)

I don't ask u to give me the answer I will not learn.

```
var dracoLoader = new THREE.DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath( 'js/draco_decoder.js' );

let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(); // I use this as all the video i saw but i you coud explain it (does it help to pack data or just to encode?)
loader.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );

loader.load('assets/BM1294_EOS_TABLE_220X280_OUVERT/BM1294.gltf',
function(gltf){
    console.log(gltf);
    let mesh = gltf.scene.children[0]; //one of my model
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Thank you If you help :)

Comment: Have you considered to use [Object3D.getObjectByName()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName)? You can invoke this method on your loaded `gltf.scene` and query single components of your asset by (node) names.

Comment: Are you talking about nodes name in gltf.parser.json.node ?

Comment: I'm referring to the names of `glTF` components like meshes, materials etc..

Comment: i ll try this and tell you after

Comment: ok, but when I look for the name of the mesh I already got the object, what is the utility of this?  I just want the path of the resources of each mesh etc and store them and use it late (change dynamically the color)

Comment: I look all my components in , ```gltf.scene.children.forEach(function(children) {children.name});```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify plain JSON, without using threejs objects, you should probably load the JSON outside of GLTFLoader first. For example:

```
// Load JSON using the native fetch() API.
fetch('model.gltf')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    // View and edit the glTF JSON content.
    console.log(json);
    json.materials[0].baseColorFactor = [1, 0, 0, 1];

    // Parse the modified glTF JSON using THREE.GLTFLoader.
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.parse( jsonString, '', ( gltf ) => {
      // Add the result to the scene.
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
  });
```

> **NOTE**: This assumes you are using the `.gltf` extension. Files ending in `.glb` are binary, and parsing them isn't covered by this answer. You can convert easily between the two variants with [glTF-Pipeline](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-pipeline).

Modifying the glTF content in complex ways will require some understanding of the [format specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md), and is somewhat outside the scope of a Stack Overflow question. You may find it easier to load threejs objects using GLTFLoader normally and modify those, instead.

Comment: That's a good way to make I think (not for color modification but search in the JSON file). but now is there any .getTexturePath or I have to look for, in recursive way,  every "texture.png" (name could change) in the current folder? For now, i think I found the good to select every component with .traverse in scene and store them in a array

Comment: it s maybe because I don't understand the material and texture of components. 
I m like super bad in 3D and texture, material, envmap and UV I don't understand, the model looks better on other viewers. Mine looks like its basic shape.

Comment: You'll have a much, much easier time working with threejs objects than trying to edit a raw glTF file with your application code  – if you're trying to get something to look right, use the tools threejs provides or edit the file in a modelling tool like Blender.